# PyInstaller issue with creating working executable

Tags: anaconda, pyqt5, python-3.5, pyinstaller, spyder

I've created a Windows 64-bit desktop app and it works when I run it from Spyder (part of Anaconda) and I'm using pyinstaller 3.3.1 (using the terminal within Anaconda) to create an EXE, the CLI code I'm using is:

pyinstaller --clean -w -F -i "C:\Users\User\Python_program\icon.ico" program.pyw

I go to the 'dist' folder and double click 'program.exe' and I get this error:

[image]

The 'program.spec' file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['program.pyw'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Python_program'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='program',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='C:\\Users\\User\\Python_program\\icon.ico')
```

In the 'warnprogram.txt' within the 'build/program' folder I get this list of missing modules:

```
missing module named resource - imported by posix, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named posix - imported by os, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw, xml.sax
missing module named clr - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard, pyreadline.console.ironpython_console, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named IronPythonConsole - imported by pyreadline.console.ironpython_console, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named StringIO - imported by pyreadline.py3k_compat, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named System - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard, pyreadline.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms, pyreadline.console.ironpython_console, pyreadline.rlmain, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named sets - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named startup - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common, pyreadline.keysyms.keysyms, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named console - imported by pyreadline.console.ansi, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib, importlib.abc, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap, importlib, importlib.abc, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request
missing module named java - imported by platform, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw, xml.sax._exceptions
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named termios - imported by tty, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw, getpass
missing module named grp - imported by shutil, tarfile, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath, shutil, tarfile, http.server, webbrowser, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw, netrc, getpass
missing module named ce - imported by os, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
missing module named org - imported by copy, C:\Users\User\Python_program\program.pyw
```

What am I getting wrong, how do I correct it? Any suggestions, links to previous related questions (I have searched Stack Overflow but without any results pertaining to this particular issue) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I used this code in the cli:

pyinstaller --clean -w -F --paths C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Library\bin -i "C:\Users\User\Python_program\icon.ico" program.py

And this is the spec file which is generated:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['program.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Python_program'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='program',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False , icon='C:\\Users\\User\\Python_program\\icon.ico')
```

I still get the same result as before though and am at a loss what to do. Can anyone provide some advice on the next step in using PyInstaller please?